# Error in my own meteor materialUI app

Tags: reactjs

I created my own Meteor, Material-UI app.

The app has a folder structure:

```
RamaCRUD Created
    client
    imports
        api
```

I am adding the code for EmployeeMaster.jsx in a pastebin (deleted by editor). When I go to http://localhost:3000/EmployeeMaster, it should show the rendering but it doesn't.

Comment: Please add the relevant code *here*, do *not* link it. As-is, this question cannot be answered here for lack of detail.

Comment: reformat; remove external link (already asked to provide code in a comment)